# Settings.bundle/Root.plist in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-maui

Is anyone knows where "Settings.bundle/Root.plist" suppose to go in .Net MAUI? In Xamarin Forms it was under platform-specific project (iOS) for "shared" settings.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should replicate this on .NET MAUI by doing the same than you did on Xamarin.Forms but under YourApp > Platforms > iOS.
You will find specific platform files here like AppDelegate or Info.plist.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought. But it doesn't work. I tried different  "Build Action" for the Root.plist nothing is working.

Comment: Do you have an issue at compile or at runtime ?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking.  The issue is that iPhone/iPad device settings doesn't have my values displayed in the application settings.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/67832959/182405444-00bacef5-69fe-41cf-a77f-a93beba6e9b0.png

Comment: Look at the image, device settings have only default MAUI settings value there, all my application settings are missing.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/67832959/182405444-00bacef5-69fe-41cf-a77f-a93beba6e9b0.png

Comment: Yes indeed. I guess that's you but an issue is opened in the dotnet/maui Github. I would expect to work like describe above but that's not the case. It should be.